# Как работает программа?

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
static final int d = 8;
static int N, x, mx;
static long m;
static int[] a = new int[d];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    N = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
        x = in.nextInt();
        a[i % d] = x;
    }
    mx = 0;
    m = 0;
    for (int i = d + 1; i <= N; i++) {
        x = in.nextInt();
        if (a[i % d] > mx) {
            mx = a[i % d];
        }
        if (x * mx > m) {
            m = x * mx;
        }
        a[i % d] = x;
    }
    System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Больше всего меня интересует строка с выражением a[i % d],что она делает и как работает?Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: `a[i % d] = x` присваивает `x` элементу массива `a` с индексом, равным остатку от деления `i` на `d`...

Answer (score 2):

Это решение задачи 27 ЕГЭ по информатике. Скорее всего условие такое: найти максимальное произведение элементов расстояние между которыми больше или равно 8. Заводим "окно" это массив содержащий первые 8 элементов. Далее читаем следующий и ищем макстмум из него или произведения его на элемент "окна". Вот пример такой задачиhttps://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=16402. Строка a[i%d] помещает элементы последовательности в окно по кругу.

Comment: а если нужно найти минимальное произведение?

Comment: Тогда используйте знак "меньше"

Comment: пробовал,что-то не получается(

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит привести условие вашей задачи. На поставленный вами вопрос я ответил.

Comment: условие тоже самое,которое вы написали выше,но найди минимальное произведение

Comment: Это не полное условие задачи. Если вы его прочитаете внимательно, то увидите существенные моменты, которые вы не указали. Например ограничение на величину элементов и пр.

Comment: я уже разобрался,спасибо